# Python3 pass variable to paramiko

Tags: python-3.x, ssh

So i'm taking all ips from the range 1.1.1.0 to 1.1.1.10 and individually connecting to ssh with each ip. When I run "print(host1)" it gives me the ip but when I use the variable host1 in ssh.connect I get the error "getaddrinfo() argument 1 must be string or None" and if I put  the variable host1 into quotes I get the error "can only concatenate str (not "IPv4Address") to str"

```
    start_ip = ipaddress.IPv4Address('1.1.1.0')
    end_ip = ipaddress.IPv4Address('1.1.1.10')
    for ip_int in range(int(start_ip), int(end_ip)):
    host1 = ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip_int)
    print(ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip_int))
    print(host1)
    def ssh_connect(password, code=0):
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        try:
            ssh.connect(host1, port=22, username=username, password=password, timeout=5)
```

Comment: Try moving the 'print(host1)' statement down below the 'try:' statement and my intuition is that you won't be getting what you expect as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is tab dependent.  So you had to be careful about that when you code out your control structures.  The indentation tells Python which statements should be included in your loops.  My advice is to remove the function definition until you get this piece of code working and then if you wanted to generalize the functionality later when you know Python better, better to have a piece of code that works than a piece of code that you don't quite grasp.  But spacing at the beginning of the line is used to indicate the scope of control structures.  I never saw that before I started coding with Python and it was the hardest thing for me to grasp.  It looks like you might be having trouble with that too.

If you look for the subheading 'Using IP Addresses with other modules' you'll see that you had to typecast the hostname returned by `IPv4Address` as a string by using `str(...)`

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/ipaddress.html

Comment: Yeah as soon as I put host1 = str(ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip_int) it worked. Why does an  IP have to be a string? do the periods in the IP make it where the program cant read it if it isnt a string or can it just not read the ipaddress.ipv4address part? Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's just the standard notation.